# Haskell: How to remove a non-number from a String

Tags: haskell

I have to write a code, that only returns numbers from a String.
I know how to remove a number from a String:

```
numbersInString = map removeNumbers.words
 where 
  removeNumbers ""     = ""
  removeNumbers (s:ss)
   | isNumber s = removeNumbers ss
   | otherwise  = s : removeNumbers ss
```

But I need it when deleting non-numbers.
For example:

```
removeNonNum :: String -> [String]
```

....

```
removeNonNum "234+8" == ["234", "8"]
```

Comment: Note that `words` only splits at whitespace characters, it will consider `"234+8"` to be a single word. Also note that `removeNumbers` is simply `filter isNumber`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`words` only splits on whitespace, so make your own recursive `removeNonNum` function (this code uses [`span :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> ([a], [a])`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:span)):

```hs
import Data.Char

removeNonNum :: String -> [String]
removeNonNum "" = []
removeNonNum s@(x:_)
    -- we have numbers at the start, extract them and add them to the list
    | isNumber x =
        let (numbers, rest) = span isNumber s
         -- recurse onto the remaining parts
         in numbers:removeNonNum rest
    -- we don't have numbers at the start, skip them and continue recursing
    | otherwise = removeNonNum $ dropWhile (not . isNumber) s
```